# Multiple targets with different configuration files in same meson.build?

Tags: c, meson-build

My C application can be built with different *modes* that behaves differently depending on the content of `config.h`.
In my meson.build file, I generate this header using the function `configure_file()`.

Now I'd like to improve my build system to compile binaries for multiple *modes* in a single build. That means I'll have to manage different versions of `config.h` side by side.

My plan was to create different versions of `config.h` and save them in different folders. Then, customize the include directories for each Meson target to select the header for the *mode* I am building.

Unfortunately, I discovered that you cannot specify a subfolder in the `output` option of `configure_file()`. The file will always be created in the same location as the `meson.build` currently being executed.

This means I always have to include `'.'` and cannot differentiate between the different *modes*. Note: changing the `#include` directives in the C source files is not an option.

Is there a way to work around this in Meson?

Comment: Rather than trying to save the config.h to a different directory is it possible to change directories first? i.e: mkdir config1 && cd config1 && <cmd here> && mkdir ../config2 && cd ../config2 && <different cmd here> If not that then maybe run a loop: for i in (config1, config2); do <cmd here> mkdir $i; mv config.h $i; done

Comment: Thanks for the comment, would it be possible to move the header directly from the Meson file instead of using a bash script?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. It's not a tool I use, the suggestions were just ideas I had from having encountered similar situations in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Let meson handle the configuration options natively instead of working around it by parsing options via `config.h`.

In a `meson_options.txt` file, you declare custom configuration options such as:

```
option('mode', type : 'combo', choices : ['one', 'two'], value : 'one')
```

Then, when you configure your build you can create individual build directories by calling:

```
meson buildOne -Dmode=one
ninja -C buildOne
```

and,

```
meson buildTwo -Dmode=two
ninja -C buildTwo
```

---

However, the above approach might not be desired?

Another possible method is to declare multiple `subproject()`. If your current `meson.build` is not too specific you could try the following.

Have a new main `meson.build` which deals with packaging, but also copies a template meson.build in a sub of the subproject directory, one for each mode. This might only require a few extra `../../` to compensate the different build structure.

The nice thing with the subproject declaration is, that you can override build options for that subproject.
This would effectively mean, that you have separate build directories again, but only one main build directory, and only need to call meson once.

In this line of thought, you might refactor your application, and build only the different-mode parts in dedicated subprojects/libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'll review both suggestions and see what makes more sense for my project.